# How to add a signature field to an existing PDF/A document, keeping PDF/A-3A conformancy

Tags: itext7

I'm using the following method to add a signature field to a PDF/A document (which has a PDF/A-3A conformance level) on a new page. Everything seems to work...

```
public void AddCertifiedSignature(string srcPath, string destPath)
{
    var reader = new PdfReader(srcPath);
    var writer = new PdfWriter(destPath);
    var pdfDoc = new PdfADocument(reader, writer);

    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
    var ps = new PageSize(PageSize.A4);
    var newPage = pdfDoc.AddNewPage(ps);

    var signatureRectangle = new Rectangle(36, 648, 200, 100);
    var signatureAnnotation = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(signatureRectangle);
    var signatureField = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(pdfDoc, signatureRectangle, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3A);
    signatureField.SetFieldName("SignField1");
    form.AddField(signatureField, newPage);

    pdfDoc.Close();
}
```

However, on the last line, I get an exception:

```
Additional information: Every annotation shall have at least one appearance dictionary
```

Does anyone know how to add the requested dictionary (or a better implementation)? I'm currently using iText 7.1.2.0 (.NET).

Comment: First of all, you should use `PdfADocument` instead of `PdfDocument` whenever you are working on PDF/A documents and want to keep the compliance.

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately this still means something is missing. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, however, I used your code (and converted it into java, as I am working in that) and made it working by adding

```
PdfAnnotation annotation = pdfDoc.getLastPage().getAnnotations().get(0);
PdfFormXObject appearObj = new PdfFormXObject(signatureRectangle);
PdfAnnotationAppearance appearance = new PdfAnnotationAppearance(appearObj.getPdfObject());
annotation.setNormalAppearance(appearance);
```

before the line with

```
pdfDoc.Close();
```

Not the cleanest solution, but I hope it helps ;)

Comment: Do you know of any updates to this with modern itext7 versions? It has been inconsistent for me, but it is a unique solution not found elsewhere.